# Filtering pointcloud with voxel grid giving different number of data points

Tags: ros, pcl, voxel-grid

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I try using the voxel grid filter on a pointcloud generated by the Ensenso camera. While the camera is held stationary, it gives a constant number of data points, however with a voxel grid filter of 0.01f (1cm). I've been received different number of data points back. Why is this the case.

`std::cerr width * cloud_blob->height  sor;
      sor.setInputCloud (cloud_blob);
      sor.setLeafSize (0.01f, 0.01f, 0.01f);
      sor.filter (*cloud_filtered_blob);           //pcd saved in cloud_filtered_blob
      pcl::fromPCLPointCloud2 (*cloud_filtered_blob, *cloud_filtered);     
      std::cerr width * cloud_filtered->height`

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/226294/filtering-pointcloud-with-voxel-grid-giving-different-number-of-data-points/) by [jhlim6](https://answers.ros.org/users/25845/jhlim6/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2016-02-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The voxel grid fiilter downsamples the point cloud computing a "substitute" point for all points that are found within a voxel. Due to noise in sensor data, no received point cloud is exactly the same and thus there is some variability in the number of points of the voxel grid filtered pointcloud.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2016-02-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1